# How to turn a MD5 Hash to a String?

Tags: java, eclipse, algorithm, md5

I want to turn an MD5 Hash to a string:

```
public String MD5ToString(String plain) {
    try {
        MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
        md.reset();
        md.update(plain.getBytes());
        byte[] digest = md.digest();
        BigInteger bigInt = new BigInteger(1,digest);
        String hashtext = bigInt.toString(16);
        // Now we need to zero pad it if you actually want the full 32 chars.
        while(hashtext.length() < 32 ){
            hashtext = "0"+hashtext;
        }
        return plain;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Cannot encrypt String to Hash");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

However i just get the Md5 back? Whats ms mistake?

**UPDATE:**

I changed the return type to hashtext, BUT when I want to convert a hash to a string I just get another has back:

```
String: test
Hash: 098f6bcd4621d373cade4e832627b4f6
String: fb469d7ef430b0baf0cab6c436e70375
```

Comment: An MD5 hash is a sequence of arbitrary 16 bytes, and you want to convert it to a 32 hex char string....

Comment: Is your actual goal to get the string "test" back, when you give "098f6bcd4621d373cade4e832627b4f6" to this method? This is in general impossible, a hash is *not* an encryption which you can decrypt. The goal of a hash function is actually to be non-reversible.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I didn't analyze the code carefully but you return the object `plain` which has not changed. You should return `hashText` object if you want to get MD5 string returned from the method.

Comment: however I changed to return type, BUT when I insert this hash(test) 098f6bcd4621d373cade4e832627b4f6 I just get another hash back...

Comment: I get this back: fb469d7ef430b0baf0cab6c436e70375

Answer (score 3):

To have a usable string that you can send or store easily, the usual solution is to encode it in base64 (it's about 33% shorter than in hexa).

Here's one of the numerous tutorials you can find with Google : http://www.javatips.net/blog/2011/08/how-to-encode-and-decode-in-base64-using-java

In your precise case, as you seem to want the hexa representation, maybe you simply want to change

```
return plain;
```

to

```
return hashtext;
```

Answer (score 1):

> I changed the return type to hashtext, BUT when I want to convert a hash to a string I just get another hash back.

You seem to be under a misapprehension of what hashes are.

- In general, hashing is a non-reversible transformation.  You turn the hash back into a copy of the original string / object / whatever ... because much / most of the information content of the original has been **thrown away**.  Indeed, there are an infinite number of possible input strings that hash to a given hash value, and there is no way of knowing which one is the right one.  (They are *all* right.)
- In the case of cryptographic hash functions like MD5, it is even worse.  These functions are specifically designed to be non-reversible.  Or more precisely, they are designed such that for a given the hash, the problem of recovering *a possible input* is computationally intractable.

Now it so happens that MD5 is weak ... and that if you have a large (but technically feasible) amount computational resources and time it is possible to reverse the hash.  However, that doesn't address the first bullet point.

---

The bottom line is that if you want to be able to recover the original string you need to encrypt it rather than hash it.